# How to obtain the user ID using a Stack Snippet?

Tags: javascript, html

I am planning to make a kind of hashing algorithm for a challenge in [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). In order to do so, I need to have a salted hashing algorithm. I made the hashing algorithm, but now I need to obtain the user ID of the current user on the current StackExchange site using a *Stack Snippet*, which only uses **HTML**, **CSS** and **Javascript**.

The user ID is shown here:

[image]

Note that this is not the current URL I'm located on.

Does anyone know how to do this? I found the following in the source code of the site:

```
StackExchange.init({...,"user":"fkey":...,"rep":...,"userId":2976513,"accountId":...}
```

With dots representing irrelevant data. How do I obtain the userId from this? I'm using this to make a salted hash [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7859/34388), in the Stack Snippet.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @Mr_Pouet I went through the source code of the site and tried searching for my user ID. I did find my ID in some kind of script which uses `StackExchange.init({...})`

Comment: You want to extract userid from the url?

Comment: @AnilPanwar Yes, or from the site itself. I'll add where I found the user ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StackExchange.options.user.userId` contains the current user id at any StackExchange site (it differs between the sites, even for the same user).

If the user isn't logged in, it's `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, Stack-Nippets (hosted on http://stacksnippets.net/) will **not** be permitted to access http://stackoverflow.com (like `window.top` or other cross-domain stuff etc.) due to the **same-origin policy**.
Obviously this is for security, so that malicious users can't hide malicious scripts (automating some 'user-behaviour') in stack-snippets.

**EDIT:**
although you could get the question's url:

```js
alert(document.referrer);
```

it normally does not contain the user-id:
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/[question_id]/[question_title]`

**EDIT2:**
Also, a direct link like https://stackoverflow.com/a/34550464/588079
(format `https://stackoverflow.com/a/[answer_id]/[user_id]`) will be changed/redirected to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/[question_id]/[question_title]/[answer_id]#[answer_id]`.